# Can't see any data at my firebase database at this moment

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app is ok ( with all data ) but when I go to Firebase console, after open the database ( or storage ) no data is seen.

The firebase status ( at firebase console ) is ok.

What coul be wrong please ?

Comment: I suggest you contact firebase support for this. Right now with the (lack of) information in your question it's almost impossible to give an answer.

Comment: I'll try it.Thank you.

Comment: I just loaded the console and my database shows fine. Be sure to hard-refresh your browser if you're having problems. It sometimes loses track of sign-in state and a hard refresh (cmd-R on a mac) fixes that. If the problems persists, your best route is indeed to reach out to Firebase support.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You are Firebase Support, aren't you? :)

Comment: All is ok after a hard refresh. Thank you Frank van Puffelen.

Answer (score 1):

Solved after execute a hard refresh ( CTRL + F5 ) on browser.

Answer (score 1):

For me - it was solved when I disconnected my VPN

Answer (score -2):

Go to the rules of the database and set read and write true. It worked for me.